# Reading text files in applescript

Tags: macos, text, applescript

I have been researching this for a few days... I am trying to use applescript to read a text file and check to see if it says a specific word. All the articles I have found don't explain what anything does so it is confusing... Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`words of (read POSIX file "/Users/lauri/Notes/todo.txt" as «class utf8») contains "the" -- true`

The path could also be specified as `file "Macintosh HD:Users:lauri:Notes:todo.txt"`. Without `as «class utf8»` the file would be read as MacRoman, so characters like `ä` or `’` would get jumbled up. `as Unicode text` would read it as UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks! One more question (sorry... I'm new). How would you set the variable x to what the document says?

Comment: `set x to read POSIX file "/etc/hosts"`